# uncompression error, no file system could mount root, kernel panic not syncing

Tags: linux, linux-mint, linux-kernel

I am using Linux Mint maya on vbox (Windows XP host), it's working fine without issues.

Now I would like to install it with XP(dual boot) so I made a bootable DVD with same iso which I used for vbox, but when I boot using the DVD I am getting a screen with error message and no further action.

Please check the screenshot for more details, I have no idea what it is....

[image: screen shot of error message]

Comment: Are you booting from a regular DVD drive, or it is a exteral USB DVD drive?
This screenshot was taken while trying to boot from the live CD?

Comment: regular dvd drive, yes screenshot taken while booting from live cd/dvd (by choosing "starting from comfortable mode")

Comment: It may sound silly, but the first thing I would try is to burn a second DVD, it looks like there is something wrong with the root partition, and this can be due a corrupted DVD data.

Comment: will try it now